# Firebase Doesn't Check if Email as an Account

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

So i'm working with Firebase web email authentication and I came across this issue. Firebase would only check if the password matched the one in the database IF the email exist. If the email Doesn't exist then it won't give an error message and sign in the person. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this so that Firebase check every time that the email exist and if it doesn't it returns an error message.

JavaScript

```
    function SignUserIn() {
    // Get elements
    const txtEmail = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
    const txtPassword = document.getElementById("txtPassword");

    // Get email and pass
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const password = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    //Sign In
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                window.alert('Wrong password.');
            }
            else {
                //Realtime listener
                firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(frebaseUser => {
                    if (email) {
                        window.alert("You Are Successfully Signed In! Welcome " + email);
                        window.location = 'homepage.html'; //After successful login, user will be redirected to Homepage
                        sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Not logged in');
                        window.alert("Incorrect User/Password Please Try Again");
                    }
                });

                sessionStorage.setItem(email);
            }

        }); 
}
```

HTML BODY

```
<div class="login-card">
                <div class="mlogo"><img src="LogoFINAL copy.png" alt="Medavance"> </div>

                <h1 class="title">Welcome To Medavance! </h1>
                <br>
     <!------------------------------------- Start of Login  -------------------------------------------->
                <input type="email" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input type="password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-action" onclick="SignUserIn()"> Log in </button>
                <div class="btn btn-secondary"><a href="NewAccount.html"> Sign Up</div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: _"Firebase Authentication makes building secure application easy"_ -- part of being secure is _**not telling people**_ they have the wrong password. You don't tell them "yes, that user exists but you got the wrong password". You don't tell them "no, that user doesn't exist". Because just finding valid usernames is half-way to hacking you. You only tell them "can't log you in with that username & password".

Comment: @StephenP Okay thanks i get that. But my main problem is that if i enter a email that doesn't  exist in the database i don't get the error message rather it just sign in the person, how can i avoid that and at least get the person to check if the user exist and if user doesn't exist show the error message of "You can't be logged in with that username and password." .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function() {
    // Handle success here
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(frebaseUser => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
        window.alert("You Are Successfully Signed In! Welcome " + email);
        window.location = "homepage.html";
    });
}, function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    window.alert(errorMessage);
    document.getElementById("txtPassword").value = "";
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the doc for [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword), it says you should get `auth/user-not-found` "Thrown if there is no user corresponding to the given email" but you're not checking for that in your test `if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password')` and you therefore execute the `else`, which seems to assume success.

If I understand it correctly, signInWithEmailAndPassword should only call the `.catch()` callback if there is an error, so you should never log them in if it's called.

You could check the specific errorCode to decide what to do next, but only log them in *following* the signInWithEmailAndPassword call, not in the catch function.  This also implies your catch needs to prevent continuing to execute after it.

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` also returns a *promise* "**Returns** non-null `firebase.Promise` containing non-null `firebase.User`" that you can use following the call to log the user in.

---

disclaimer: this is all from the docs, I haven't used firebase.auth() to test it.